# Python Virtual Person Error

Tags: python, file, virtual

I am making a virtual person with a lang.txt file with all of the possible questions and on the next line the response after that question. The problem I'm having is I have a variable called "lang" and it is a list, I am successfully getting the lang variable to have the value 0 as 'hello' and value 1 as 'Hi There' but when I try "if usercommand in lang:" it never seems to be in the list? Sorry if this is quite obvious, I am new... Here's my code:

```
def getin():

    command=raw_input(">> ").lower()
    return command

def getout(ucom):
    a = lang.index(ucom)
    print [a+1]


lang = []

langf=open('lang.txt', 'r')

for (en, line) in enumerate (langf):

    lang.append(line)
    print lang[en]
while True:

    x=getin()
    getout(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the newlines off the lines you're reading in as in:

```
lang.append(line.strip())
```